# PHP Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

so I'm working on this scraper for Facebook public posts. The access_token I am using was generated from the Facebook Graph API Explorer

My start URL works fine, I get the data:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/search?type=post&q=something&access_token=(access_token)&since=1412765557
```

however when I continue to the next page it stops working giving me this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- Scraping is not allowed: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php
- Public Post Search is deprecated with v2.0, v1.0 can only be used with an App created before April 30th, 2014 - and only until April 30th, 2015 (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

Although, when i try with a newer App, i get the following detailed error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#11) Post search has been deprecated",
    "type": "OAuthBaseException",
    "code": 11
  }
}
```